# Sending Variable information through a server (c#)

Tags: c#

i am working on a program for my school to track student attendance. this program works though having three separate programs work in conjunction with each other. these being a desktop client, a server client, and a database program. the desktop client works by having 3 arrays to determine students being late, absent, or in attendance. the problem i am having is sending bool values to my server, from my desktop client, because i do not know how to do this. i have searched around on the web and found vague answers related to this topic. Thanks!

-again, my problem is sending Boolean values from the desktop client to the server client. i have already been able to program a small messaging app for some practice.

cheers

Comment: What is the "server client"?  A web service?  A Windows service?  An app running on the server?  What have you tried with the "messaging app" and where are you stuck?

Comment: the server client is a windows forms application, that can host an ip and port for sending an reciving data, a similar consept to what this guy did: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AN5AtcD2Hdc

Answer (score 0):

Convert the boolean to string using .ToString(), transmit the string, and then convert it back to boolean using Boolean.Parse(theStringValue);

Comment: interesting, that may work for what i need. il give it a shot